# Python 3.9.8 fails using Black and importing `typed_ast.ast3`

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since updating to Python 3.9.8, we get an error while using [Black](https://github.com/psf/black) in our [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) pipeline.

```
black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- exit code: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../.cache/pre-commit/repol9drvp84/py_env-python3/bin/black", line 5, in <module>
    from black import patched_main
  File "../.cache/pre-commit/repol9drvp84/py_env-python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from typed_ast import ast3, ast27
  File "../.cache/pre-commit/repol9drvp84/py_env-python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typed_ast/ast3.py", line 40, in <module>
    from typed_ast import _ast3
ImportError: ../.cache/pre-commit/repol9drvp84/py_env-python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typed_ast/_ast3.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape
```

The error can be easily reproduced with:

```
% pip install typed_ast
% python3 -c 'from typed_ast import ast3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/typed_ast/_ast3.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape
```

Currently the only workaround is downgrading to Python 3.9.7.

Is another fix available?

See also *[Bug#998854: undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1829077.html)*

Comment: For me it seems as if you use an external library `typed_ast` with a module `_ast3` that is not meant for external use (indicated by the leading underscore). Either ask the developers of the library or try to find a documented way.

Comment: @Matthias you are right, but as the upper stacktrace says the error comes also up by importing `ast3'`. Thx for the comment i updated title and description.

Comment: Did you update ``black``? The more recent versions should not depend on ``typed_ast``.

Comment: See also GitHub [python/typed_ast#169](https://github.com/python/typed_ast/issues/169)

Comment: This was [mentioned on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417674/bad-first-question-audit-experience-incorrect-audit-audit-doesnt-help-reviewe#comment906730_417674).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The initial error was a failing [Python Black](https://github.com/psf/black) pipeline. Black failed because it was pinned to an older version which now fails with Python 3.9.8.

**Updating Black to the latest version, [21.10b0](https://github.com/psf/black/releases/tag/21.10b0), fixed the error for me.**

See also [typed_ast issue #169](https://github.com/python/typed_ast/issues/169#issuecomment-964360487):

> For others who may find this in a search, I ran into this problem via
> black because I had black pinned to an older version. The current
> version of black appears to no longer use typed-ast and thus won't
> encounter this issue.

Using the latest `typed-ast` version >=`1.5.0` seems to work as well.

E.g., `pip install typed-ast --upgrade`

Comment: `mypy` also has this issue (https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9488) but it's solved in the latest version (v0.930)